# Question about Klein-Gordon field Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, hamiltonian, klein-gordon-equation

I was studying Klein-Gordon field with Peskin QFT. I know that the Hamiltonian of the scalar field can be written as $$H=\int d^3x\left[\frac{1}{2}\pi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2\right]$$
However, when the book computes the time dependence of $\pi$, Heisenberg equation of motion is written as the image below.
[image]

In the image, Hamiltonian is different from above. Specifically, $\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2$ became $-\frac{1}{2}\phi\nabla^2\phi$. How is this possible?

Comment: Integrate by parts and ignore the boundary term.

Comment: Quite often in physics when a minus sign under an integral appears out of nowhere, the author has quietly done integration by parts and discarded the boundary term.

Answer (score 1):

First, integrate by parts

$$(\nabla\phi)^2=\nabla\cdot(\phi\nabla\phi)-\phi\nabla^2\phi.$$

Then use Gauss Theorem

$$\iiint\,dV\,\nabla\cdot(\phi\nabla\phi)=\iint\,dS\,\phi\nabla\phi.$$

We always assume that the field $\phi$ goes to zero in infinity, so this "boundary term" is ignored and you get $(\nabla\phi)^2=-\phi\nabla^2\phi$ under integral.