# Peskin Schroeder 2.44 application

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian, integration

After 2.44, the book calculates the commutators of $\phi$ and $\pi$ with the Hamiltonian. But in the first expression the Hamiltonian has a different form than in the second. The first one matches equation 2.8.
$$H = \int {d^3x\left[\frac{1}{2}\pi^2 + \frac{1}{2}\ (\nabla\phi)^2 + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2  \right]}$$
But in the second one, the Hamiltonian has this form inside the conmutator.

$$\int {d^3x'\left[\frac{1}{2}\pi^2(x',t) + \frac{1}{2}\phi(x',t)(-\nabla^2 +m^2)\phi(x',t) \right]}$$

How can you exchange the gradient squared with a $\phi\nabla^2\phi$ term?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: When negative signs mysteriously appear under integrals in physics, the first thing you should ask is if integration by parts has been used. Note here that the so-called "boundary term" has been discarded since by assumption the fields vanish at spatial infinity, i.e. $\lim_{x_i\rightarrow\pm\infty}\phi(x_i)=0$.

Comment: Duplicate of [Question about Klein-Gordon field Lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637655/question-about-klein-gordon-field-lagrangian)